# Scrollable menu in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, menu, scroll

I am trying to create a scrollable menu list in JavaScript and I am following a tutorial
http://javascript.internet.com/navigation/menu-scroll.html

But nothing appears on my page. This is what I have tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ScrollMenu.js"></script>
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

<!-- Original:  Randy Bennett (rbennett@thezone.net) -->
<!-- Web Site:  http://home.thezone.net/~rbennett/utility/javahead.htm -->

<!-- This script and many more are available free online at -->
<!-- The JavaScript Source!! http://javascript.internet.com -->

    <!-- Begin
    function buildMenu() {
        speed=35;
        topdistance=100;
        items=6;
        y=-50;
        ob=1;
        if (navigator.appName == "Netscape") {
            v=".top=",dS="document.",sD="";
        }
        else {
            v=".pixelTop=",dS="",sD=".style";
        }
    }

    function scrollItems() {
        if (ob<items+1) {
            objectX="object"+ob; y+=10; eval(dS + objectX + sD + v + y);
            if (y<topdistance) setTimeout("scrollItems()",speed);
            else y=-50, topdistance+=40, ob+=1, setTimeout("scrollItems()",speed);
        }
    }
// End -->
</SCRIPT>
</head>
<body onLoad="buildMenu(), scrollItems();">
    <a href="pic.html">hello</a>
    <a href="pic.html">Link 1!</a>
    <a href="pic.html">Link 1!</a>
    <a href="pic.html">Link 1!</a>
    <a href="pic.html">Link 1!</a>
    <a href="pic.html">Link 1!</a>
    <div id="object1" style="position:absolute; visibility:show; left:25px; top:-50px; z-index:2">
        <table border=1 width=150 bgcolor=80FFFF>
            <td>
                <a href="pic.html">Link 1!</a>
            </td>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="object2" style="position:absolute; visibility:show; left:25px; top:-50px; z-index:2">
        <table border=1 width=150 bgcolor=80FFFF>
            <td>
                <a href="pic.html">Link 2!</a>
            </td>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="object3" style="position:absolute; visibility:show; left:25px; top:-50px; z-index:2">
        <table border=1 width=150 bgcolor=80FFFF>
            <td>
                <a href="pic.html">Link 3!</a>
            </td>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="object4" style="position:absolute; visibility:show; left:25px; top:-50px; z-index:2">
        <table border=1 width=150 bgcolor=80FFFF>
            <td>
                <a href="pic.html">Link 4!</a>
            </td>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="object5" style="position:absolute; visibility:show; left:25px; top:-50px; z-index:2">
        <table border=1 width=150 bgcolor=80FFFF>
            <td>
                <a href="pic.html">Link 5!</a>
            </td>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="object6" style="position:absolute; visibility:show; left:25px; top:-50px; z-index:2">
        <table border=1 width=150 bgcolor=80FFFF>
            <td>
                <a href="pic.html">Link 6!</a>
            </td>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help please?? :)

THanks so much
C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change scrollItems() To this code

```
function scrollItems() {
    if (ob<items+1) {
        objectX="object"+ob; y+=10; 
        document.getElementById(objectX).style.top = y + "px"
        if (y<topdistance) setTimeout("scrollItems()",speed);
        else y=-50, topdistance+=40, ob+=1, setTimeout("scrollItems()",speed);
    }
}
```

See please if it works fine with you

Answer (score 1):

Changing to Kronass's code is good. I actually got the code working as well, but s/he bet me to it.

You should also note, that your body onload should not have a comma in it, but a semicolon.

i.e. you have:

```
<body onLoad="buildMenu(), scrollItems();">
```

Which should be

```
<body onLoad="buildMenu(); scrollItems();">
```

In your HTML style, you should have

```
visibility: visible;
```

NOT

```
visibility: show;
```

The reason that the original code doesn't work, is that it is VERY old. (in Internet terms)